# Add tab in front of each line

Tags: normal-mode

I'm working with python code. After some modifications, I want to update the identation but obviously, select everything and press '=' doesn't work, python being python.

So, is there any other way to add (and/or remove) some character (here, tabs) at the beggining of each line ?

Comment: Try this: `:help v_>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Sato mentioned in comments, `:help v_>` will show you help for the best tool you can use for this.  `>>` in normal mode will indent the current line; `>3>` will indent the current line and the following two lines; `<<` will decrease indentation.

Another feature that works will in combination with `>` can be found at `:help text-objects`.  (`aB`, `a[`, and so on.)  For example in C-style code that uses curly braces, `>aB` or `>iB` to indent the current block *including* curly braces, or only indent the lines *between* the curly braces, respectively.  For Python code, `>ap` (indent a paragraph) may be more useful, but using visual mode to select the lines as described in `:help v_>` is even more adjustable.

For the general answer to "How to add a character/some text at the beginning of each line?" i.e., when you want to insert something other than tabs or spaces, there are a couple ways:

`:%normal Itext to insert` will prepend `text to insert` to every line in the file.  `%` can be replaced with any range you like.  (See `:help range` and also `:help :normal`)

Or you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>to enter blockwise-visual mode, use `j` and `k` to select a column of characters, then `I` (capital) to insert text at that point in *all* selected lines.  (It will only be visible in all the lines after you <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then make another motion of any sort.)  This has the advantage that you can enter text at ANY point in the line, not only at the beginning.  (See `:help v_b_I`)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

1. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get into normal mode
2. `:set number` This will show the line numbers
3. Run `:<from_line_number>,<to_line_number>>`

For example, `:279,$>` will indent all lines from line number 279 by 1 tab space (the actual indent amount depends on various options).

Comment: I've made some formatting edits, and also changed "command mode" to "normal mode"—while to some they are synonymous, to others "command" means "command-line" (aka Ex), which you get to with `:`. "Normal" is the least ambiguous option. cf. `:help Normal-mode` which uses both, but clearly prefers "Normal."

Comment: (PS if you have multiple accounts, please let us know that they belong to the same person so that we may merge them. That also makes it easier for you to, _e.g._, [edit] your own posts, accrue reputation, etc.)